# Flash player overlays the absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css, flash, actionscript

the flash player overlays the div absolute positioned element, i have set his index to 100-200-300, but it doesn't change anything, how can this be fixed?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the flash code, I remember there's an option for this. I'm not sure you can fix that using css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You may alter the [wmode property](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_) which impacts Flash's drawing in host application.

Update: Should you wish to make DIV on top of the Flash, besides setting wmode of Flash, you can also use jQuery's bgiframe plugin which would wrap your DIV into an iframe.  IFrame generally overlays better on top of other elements such as Flash and dropdown list.